# OAuth2Client get extra Facebook data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to work out how I can request a Facebook user's email address with a custom OAuth2Client, however there is a severe lack of documentation to do this from what I can find on Google. I have set the permissions on the facebook app, but I've read that the default Facebook client from Microsoft does not request email and the only way to do so is to roll your own.

Does anybody know any good resources or code that can showcase how to request extra data from Facebook by writing a custom OAuth2Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before redirecting to FB you needs to specify parameters like below

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["state"] = returnUrl;
        parameters["scope"] = "email";
```

and this is how you can get the information,since in many cases users have privacy on their email addresses so you'll not get email in that case

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                    dynamic me = fbClient.Get("/me");

 FBModel f = new FBModel();//Making Model class object to pass values to it                  
                    f.Name = me.name;
                    f.FirstName = me.first_name;
                    f.LastName = me.last_name;
                    f.Gender = me.gender;            
                    if (me.email != null)
                    {
                        f.Username = me.email;
                        f.isEmail = true;

                    }
```